# Javascript onKeyDown function

Tags: javascript

I have written a simple javascript code and added event listener for `onKeyDown/onKeyUp` . It works just fine and detects the Control key as required. However the Control key shows pressed even when I am using OS shortcuts.

To be specific I am on Ubuntu and use `Ctrl+Alt+ arrow keys` to switch workspaces. So when I switch the workspace and come back to Chrome, it shows `Control` key pressed already.

I dont mind it but even when the shortcut keys are released, `onkeyup` method is not called and hence the status shows `Ctrl` key pressed. 
How do I avoid this?

Below is my code:

```
function keypressedfn(e){
if(e.which == CTRL_KEY){
    console.log("isCtrl pressed");
    isCtrl=true;
    if(isWheel){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
};

function keyreleasedfn(e){
if(e.which == CTRL_KEY){
    console.log("isCtrl released");
    isCtrl=false;
    isWheel=false;
}
};

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).keydown(keypressedfn);
$(document).keyup(keyreleasedfn);
});
```

Comment: Are the key events added to document element?

Comment: If you think the issue is specific to Ubuntu and Chrome, add tags.

Comment: @Piwwoli , Yes the key events are added to the document element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using Ctrl to change workspaces, then your window w/ js running is losing focus before the keyup event. 
you could bind an event to the window object that discards keydown whenever the window loses focus:

> window.onblur = function(){console.log("blur");};

without seeing more of your code i can't say much more than that

Answer (score 1):

It is not standard practice to detect the `KeyDown` event of `Control` key (or `Alt`, or `Shift`, for that matter).

What you should do is find if your desired key is pressed. For example, if you want to save something when `Ctrl+S` is pressed, look for `S` key.

```
var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode; // keyCode will be 'S'

if (e.ctrlKey && keyCode == 83) {
    // Ctrl + S pressed. Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Probably safer to use `var keyCode = typeof e.which == "number"? e.which : e.keyCode` since if `e.which` is 0, then it may attempt `e.keyCode` which may not be supported in that browser. And what you are getting is the *keyCode*, not the *charCode*.

Comment: @RobG: Well I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing out. But could the key code really be 0 in practice?

Comment: 0 is *null*, I don't know how to get that from a key press, however there are different types of input device besides keyboards and events may be dispatched by other means.